# Applescript string matching failed

Tags: applescript

I want it so that if the current date matches the string, it will log "works!". However it doesn't seem to work.

```
set datesubmit to "27, May, 2016"
set trydate to {day, month, year} of (current date)
log (trydate)
log (datesubmit)
if trydate is equal to datesubmit then
    log ("works!")
end if
```

I tried to make sure they are both string type variables but I can't get it to equal. This was the output:

```
(*27, May, 2016*)
(*27, May, 2016*)
```

Can someone tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: In your example `datesubmit` and `trydate` are not both strings and therefore your `if` statement is doing exactly what it's supposed to because they are not equal. You cannot go by the appearance of what the `log` command shows!  You should probably read [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html), specifically the sections on _date_ and _text_.  Change `set trydate to {day, month, year} of (current date)` to `set trydate to date string of (current date)` and it should then compare as strings.

Comment: I don't think *trydate* is set to a string as you expect because if you change datesubmit to "27May2016" it works!

Comment: Klanomath post it as an answer so I can mark you as correct.

Comment: @klanomath, you said "_... if you change datesubmit to "27May2016" it works!_", well it doesn't work on my system when I do that!

Comment: @user3439894 well it works for my system. Change log(trydate) to log(trydate as string). Tell use what happens. Klanomath solved my problem.

Comment: @user3439894 hmm in second attempt it indeed doesn't work...strange

Comment: @klanomath maybe because for you you changed day?

Comment: @Bradman175 Now it works again but with `if trydate as string is equal to datesubmit then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trying I come to the conclusion that a `variable` set `to {day, month, year} of (current date)` isn't a "string" with the form "day, month, year" but "daymonthyear".

So you may change the script to

```
set datesubmit to "27May2016"
set trydate to {day, month, year} of (current date)
log (datesubmit)
log (trydate)
if trydate as string is equal to datesubmit then
    log ("works!")
else
    log ("doesn't work!")
end if
```

which is not very elegant.

Alternatively you may choose:

```
set datesubmit to "Friday 27 May 2016"
set trydate to date string of (current date)
log (datesubmit)
log (trydate)
if trydate is equal to datesubmit then
    log ("works!")
else
    log ("doesn't work!")
end if
```

You always have to add the weekday in the first variable though.

The best proposal (made by the OP itself) is:

```
set datesubmit to "27, May, 2016"
set trydate to day of (current date) & ", " & month of (current date) & ", " & year of (current date) as string
log (datesubmit)
log (trydate)
if trydate is equal to datesubmit then
    log ("works!")
else
    log ("doesn't work!")
end if
```

Comment: I just did: set trydate to day of (current date) & ", " & month of (current date) & ", " & year of (current date) as string

Comment: Then you can omit the "as string" in the if statement.

Comment: @Bradman175 I tried similar solutions but AppleScript-Editor always complained about them because I got all the &"() etc. wrong...

Comment: does mine not work though?

Comment: @Bradman175 It works of course ;-)

Comment: good you included in your answer. Was just about to ask you to do that XD

Answer (score 2):

[klanomath's helpful answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239751/28668) contains viable solutions, but the **cleanest and simplest approach is to compare items of the same type directly**:

```
set datesubmit to {27, May, 2016}
set trydate to {day, month, year} of (current date)

if trydate = datesubmit then
    log "works!"
end if
```

Both date variables now contain **3-element lists** (`{ ..., ..., ... }`) that can be directly compared with `is equal to` or simply `=`.

Note that `May` is a built-in month constant that evaluates to `5` in a numerical context (it is *not* a *string*).

Comment: Ooh trying to steal klanomath's place lol. Yours does look better tho.

Comment: `if trydate = datesubmit then` was one of the first things I tried and it didn't work on my system, not sure why though.  Although, today it's working! +1

Comment: I just figured out why it didn't work... at the time I tried it was still the 26th as it was about quarter till midnight here at my location.  So it actually worked by not outputting `(*works!*)` as it wasn't the 27th yet.

Comment: Why can't I mark 2 as correct?